# Send Email to multiple recipients from .txt file with Python smtplib

Tags: python, email

I try to send mails from python to multiple email-addresses, imported from a .txt file, I've tried differend syntaxes, but nothing would work...

The code:

```
s.sendmail('sender@mail.com', ['recipient@mail.com', 'recipient2@mail.com', 'recipient3@mail.com'], msg.as_string())
```

So I tried this to import the recipient-addresses from a .txt file:

```
urlFile = open("mailList.txt", "r+")
mailList = urlFile.read()
s.sendmail('sender@mail.com', mailList, msg.as_string())
```

The mainList.txt contains:

```
['recipient@mail.com', 'recipient2@mail.com', 'recipient3@mail.com']
```

But it doesn't work...

I've also tried to do:

```
... [mailList] ... in the code, and '...','...','...' in the .txt file, but also no effect
```

and

```
... [mailList] ... in the code, and ...','...','... in the .txt file, but also no effect...
```

Does anyone knows what to do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
urlFile = open("mailList.txt", "r+")
mailList = [i.strip() for i in urlFile.readlines()]
```

and put each recipient on its own *line* (i.e. separate with a line break).

Answer (score 35):

This question has sort of been answered, but not fully.  The issue for me is that "To:" header wants the emails as a string, and the sendmail function wants it in a list structure.

```
# list of emails
emails = ["banjer@example.com", "slingblade@example.com", "dude@example.com"]

# Use a string for the To: header
msg['To'] = ', '.join( emails )

# Use a list for sendmail function
s.sendmail(from_email, emails, msg.as_string() )
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sendmail` function requires a list of addresses, you are passing it a string.

If the addresses within the file are formatted as you say, you could use `eval()` to convert it into a list.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be a real list. So, with this in the file:

```
recipient@mail.com,recipient2@mail.com,recipient3@mail.com
```

you can do

```
mailList = urlFile.read().split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

to_addrs in the sendmail function call is actually a dictionary of all the recipients (to, cc, bcc) and not just to.

While providing all the recipients in the functional call, you also need to send a list of same recipients in the msg as a comma separated string format for each types of recipients.  (to,cc,bcc).  But you can do this easily but maintaing either separate lists and combining into string or convert strings into lists.

Here are the examples

```
TO = "1@to.com,2@to.com"
CC = "1@cc.com,2@cc.com"
msg['To'] = TO
msg['CC'] = CC
s.sendmail(from_email, TO.split(',') + CC.split(','), msg.as_string())
```

or

```
TO = ['1@to.com','2@to.com']
CC = ['1@cc.com','2@cc.com']
msg['To'] = ",".join(To)
msg['CC'] = ",".join(CC)
s.sendmail(from_email, TO+CC, msg.as_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlFile = open("mailList.txt", "r")

list=[]        #create an empty list

for line in urlFile.readlines():
    x=line.strip()
    list.append(x)

print(list)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**