# Using a dictionary to pull Email Addresses. Some key's have multiple emails, how do I send to all emails?

Tags: python, email, dictionary

Using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Platform.

I am trying to send email based on ID.
I currently have ID: Email set up in a dictionary to pull from.  However some ID's have multiple emails associated.  How would I set that up to send an email to each recipient.  I've tried [ID]:[email, email], and it seems to only send to the first email address listed.  Thanks in advance.
Dictionary creation code below.

```
COLS = ['rep_id', 'email', 'password']
with open('commissionrepemaillist.csv', 'r') as infile:
    email_dict = {
        row[0]: dict(zip(COLS, row)) for row in csv.reader(infile)
    }
```

And I'm using that to assign the variable I use to send the email

```
email = email_dict[ID]['email']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer with only the info given so far, but it looks like `d[ID]=[email1, email2, etc]` where `d` is your dictionary.  `d[ID]` is a list of emails corresponding to `ID`.  If you want to send email to a list of email addresses, this question is a good one to look at: [Send Email to multiple recipients from .txt file with Python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941811/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-from-txt-file-with-python-smtplib)

Comment: OK, well now the question has changed...  Starting from `email = email_dict[ID]['email']` what is the result of `print(email)` ?

Comment: Is `'email'` a string that appears in `COLS`?  Does it appear more than once?

Comment: I've added the definition of COLS.  It's the "header" or "label" for a row in the csv file.  `print email`  prints the email address of the correlating ID as a string.

Comment: I think your suggested solution points me in the direction I need to be going in.  Thank you.

Comment: Try `print(email)`.  Should print a list of email addresses.  If it does, then it sounds like the question is how to send email to a list of email addresses.  The answer to that question is covered reasonably well in the linked answer given above.  Or is that not the question?